# Load and execute entire contents of a PHP file when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

As I am somewhat of a beginner in PHP and JQuery / AJAX coding, I am having a great deal of difficulty trying to accomplish the following task.

I have a file named footer_data.php which contains the following code (this is the entire code contained within the file):

```
<?php 
if ($setting['facebook_on'] == 1) {
    if (isset($_GET['task']) && $_GET['task'] != 'facebook_register')
        include 'includes/wss_facebook.php';

    if ((isset($user['facebook']) && $user['facebook'] == 1) || ($user['login_status'] == 0)) {
        ?>

        <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));

      // Init the SDK upon load
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '<?php echo $setting['facebook_appid'];?>', // App ID
          channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/includes/facebook_channel.php', // Path to your Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        <?php if ($user['login_status'] == 0) { ?>
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
            window.location = "<?php echo $setting['site_url'];?>/facebook_auth.php"
        });
        <?php } ?>
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function() {
            window.location = "<?php echo $setting['site_url'];?>/login.php?action=logout"
        });

        <?php if ($user['login_status'] == 1) { ?>
          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if (response.status == '1') {
                  window.location = "<?php echo $setting['site_url'];?>/login.php?action=logout";
              }
          });
        <?php } ?>

      } 
    </script>



<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Currently, the above code which is contained within the file footer_data.php will be executed every time a visitor visits any web page on my website. In other words, the code is executed on page load.

What I am trying to do is get the entire code that is contained in the footer_data.php file to be executed only when a visitor clicks on a button.

I know that this could be accomplished using JQuery / AJAX, but I have no idea how to incorporate AJAX / JQuery within the above code that I have posted.

To any respondents, please if possible, could you post complete code and not just code snippets.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` of your `button` is `clickMe` then, try this to only **executate** the file:

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'footer_data.php',
      success: function(data) {
        alert("code executed!");
      }
    });
});
```

and this to executate and load its content to a HTML element, i.e. a `div`:

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $('#yourDiv').load('footer_data.php');
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more details.

Comment: The code you posted where should I place it? In a separate file or can I place it in the footer_data.php file?

Comment: In your `index.php` after the `jquery` lib, in `<script>HereGoesTheCode</script>` you need a `button` and an element to load the content, can be a `div`.